# What's wrong with my integrated camera?

Tags: camera, integrated-camera

I have a T500 Lenovo Thinkpad, Windows 7 Enterprise, 32bit, Service Pack 1.
When I hit Fn F6, it says "The camera is being used by another application".
It stopped working when the mother board was replaced ~4 weeks ago. The camera does work when booting from a Fedora live cd.
I tried the Microsoft driver, 6.1.7601.17514.
I also tried the Lenovo driver, 1.32.500.0 from Ricoh, dated 10/23/2009. It behaves the same with that driver.

How do I find out what application it thinks is using the camera?

Comment: please list OS and version. This will help folks answer your question. I forget to do it all the time. Regardless of OS, check something like 'running processes' and list them.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the drivers, OS or camera application?

Comment: updated with more information.

Comment: there are 91 running processes. what's a good way to export them?

Comment: @Linker3000 I don't think installing SP's for other operating systems makes anything better.

Comment: Do you have the face-recognition software enabled?

Comment: @Dustin not on purpose. How do I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may well be that nothing is actually trying to use it, just that the driver is corrupt or incorrect. Try installing the Lenovo driver from [here](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-70443)

Edit: Original link was incorrect.

Comment: behaves the same with that driver too.